WooCommerce Add to cart issue
I have been trying to add a custom functionality via code snippet to my WooCommerce product page, there are two error in the logs :


ajax-single-add-to-c….min.js?ver=2.2.9:1POST https://giftarticlewala.com/?wc-ajax=woostify_single_add_to_cart 500 (Internal Server Error)buttons.length.buttons.forEach.ele.onclick  @   ajax-single-add-to-c….min.js?ver=2.2.9:1ajax-single-add-to-c….min.js?ver=2.2.9:1Response {type: 'basic', url: 'https://giftarticlewala.com/?wc-ajax=woostify_single_add_to_cart', redirected: false, status: 500, ok: false, …}ajax-single-add-to-c….min.js?ver=2.2.9:1POST https://giftarticlewala.com/?wc-ajax=woostify_single_add_to_cart 500 (Internal Server Error)buttons.length.buttons.forEach.ele.onclick  @   ajax-single-add-to-c….min.js?ver=2.2.9:1a   @   front-end.js?ver=3.0.7:1(anonymous) @   front-end.js?ver=3.0.7:1(anonymous) @   front-end.js?ver=3.0.7:1(anonymous) @   front-end.js?ver=3.0.7:1(anonymous) @   front-end.js?ver=3.0.7:1M   @   front-end.js?ver=3.0.7:1(anonymous) @   front-end.js?ver=3.0.7:1S   @   front-end.js?ver=3.0.7:1Promise.then (async)        k   @   front-end.js?ver=3.0.7:1b.setState  @   front-end.js?ver=3.0.7:1(anonymous) @   front-end.js?ver=3.0.7:1a   @   front-end.js?ver=3.0.7:1(anonymous) @   front-end.js?ver=3.0.7:1setTimeout (async)      c   @   front-end.js?ver=3.0.7:1



customized-car-keychain/:411POST https://giftarticlewala.pythonanywhere.com/customize-image 500 (INTERNAL SERVER ERROR)(anonymous)   @   customized-car-keychain/:411customized-car-keychain/:411POST https://giftarticlewala.pythonanywhere.com/customize-image 500 (INTERNAL SERVER ERROR)(anonymous)  @   customized-car-keychain/:411a   @   front-end.js?ver=3.0.7:1(anonymous) @   front-end.js?ver=3.0.7:1(anonymous) @   front-end.js?ver=3.0.7:1(anonymous) @   front-end.js?ver=3.0.7:1(anonymous) @   front-end.js?ver=3.0.7:1M   @   front-end.js?ver=3.0.7:1(anonymous) @   front-end.js?ver=3.0.7:1S   @   front-end.js?ver=3.0.7:1Promise.then (async)        k   @   front-end.js?ver=3.0.7:1b.setState  @   front-end.js?ver=3.0.7:1(anonymous) @   front-end.js?ver=3.0.7:1a   @   front-end.js?ver=3.0.7:1(anonymous) @   front-end.js?ver=3.0.7:1setTimeout (async)      c   @   front-end.js?ver=3.0.7:1



My code:
add_action('woocommerce_after_add_to_cart_button', 'custom_customize_now_button', 1);
    function custom_customize_now_button() { global $product;
    // Define product IDs eligible for customization
    $eligible_product_ids = [5001]; // Add more product IDs as needed
    
    // Check if the current product is eligible for customization
    if (in_array($product->get_id(), $eligible_product_ids)) {
        // Echo the "Customize Now" button
        echo '<button type="button" class="single_add_to_cart_button button alt" id="customizeNowButton" style="margin-top: 15px;">Customize Now</button>';
    
        echo '<script>
        document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
            document.getElementById("customizeNowButton").addEventListener("click", function () {
                var frontText = document.querySelector(\'input[name="text_0524844621"]\').value;
                var backText = document.querySelector(\'input[name="text-5320109953"]\').value;
                var productID = "'.$product->get_id().'";
                var variationID = document.querySelector(\'input[name="variation_id"]\') ? document.querySelector(\'input[name="variation_id"]\').value : "";
    
                var data = {
                    product_id: productID,
                    front_text: frontText,
                    back_text: backText,
                    variation_id: variationID
                };
    
                fetch("https://giftarticlewala.pythonanywhere.com/customize-image", {
                    method: "POST",
                    headers: {
                        "Content-Type": "application/json"
                    },
                    body: JSON.stringify(data),
                    mode: "cors",
                })
                .then(response => response.json())
                .then(data => {
                    if (data.image_url) {
                        var imgWindow = window.open("", "CustomizedProductImage");
                        imgWindow.document.write(\'<img src="\' + data.image_url + \'" alt="Customized Product Image" />\');
                    } else {
                        alert("Failed to customize product.");
                    }
                })
                .catch(error => {
                    console.error("Error:", error);
                    alert("Error customizing product.");
                });
            });
        });
        </script>';
    }
}

When am running the same API on postman it totally works fine with the same post data, I think there is some issue with my theme and the code snippet. I have been facing this issue single 2 days but could not find any solution lately. Please if anyone could guide me or help me, it would be appreciated.

The requests you are making from the client side are getting a 500 (Internal Server Error) response, so the very first thing you should do now, is go check what the PHP error log has to say about the reason. (And enable WP Debug Mode, if you have not done so yet.)
